# Refresh (or resize) view

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I can have from 1 to 4 views (subview) in one container (mainview). I need to get one subview to dynamically resize and fill the mainview, when the other subviews are collapsed (by a button click action). Hopefully what follows explains it good enough.

The subviews are loaded into the mainview through its constructor.

MainView Code Behind:

```
// this code is in a foreach
ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
column.Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star);
this.gridMainView.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
subView.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 
    this.gridOnMainView.ColumnDefinitions.IndexOf(column));
this.gridOnMainView.Children.Add(subView);
```

On the mainview, I have a button that, through the mainview's view model, successfully collapses all but one of the subviews (the active subview does not collapse). Although the non-active subviews collapse, the active subview does not resize.

Button on mainview that causes the action:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Meter" Command="{Binding HideSubViewsAction}" Width="50" Margin="0,10,0,0" Cursor="Hand" />
```

The grid in subview that has a bound visibility property:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsCollapsed, Converter={StaticResource     
    booleanToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=SubViewVisibility}">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <Viewbox>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding OutputVoltage}" />
            <Label Content="v" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Border>
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Viewbox>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Label Content="{Binding OutputCurrent}" />
            <Label Content="mA" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Border>
...Other markup
</Grid>
```

The converter just checks the boolean IsCollapsed and converts true to "Collapsed" and false to "Visible"

When the non-active subviews are collapsed, the left over active subview does not re-size. How can I get the lone active subview to re-size when the other subviews are collapsed? I don't know how many views will be in the main view. There can be from 1 to 4 subviews. Course, if only 1, then I disable the collapsing button. If needed, I can refactor the code to create the subviews differently.

Comment: Remove all this and use a `DockPanel`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Replace the Code Behind's Grid with a Dock Panel? And then remove the code behind where it uses columns?

Comment: I changed the main grid to a DockPanel and it still does not resize when the non-active subviews are collapsed. I added LastChildFill and that did not cause the last visible subview to take up the space. Also, the last item in the DockPanel takes up more space than the others. I need them to all be the same width, when visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to have `ColumnSpan` update, when all the sub-views are collapsed.  One simple way to do this would be to add a binding to each subview, in the constructor foreach:

```
subView.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, new Binding("SubViewColumnSpan"));
```

Now add the property `ColumnSpan SubViewColumnSpan` to your view model.  Use the `HideSubViewsAction` command to set it equal to 10 (or a number at minimum the number of columns in the Grid).

The above is a start, but of course, you'll have to set the `SubViewColumnSpan` property back to 1 when another sub-view is re-expanded.

(Note: given that this approach is likely to become <s>tedious</s> cumbersome as your requirements grow in complexity, consider designing a [custom `Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to handle the sub-view layouts.)

Comment: Nice! I don't know why I did not think about the columns, but it is nice having smart poeple in these forums to helps us less fortunate in the brain department :) Now, I need to see if I can get smart enough to create a custom panel to do this.

Comment: @MikeCollins the custom panels stuff takes a bit of time investment to learn, but once learned it is very useful for creating custom layouts.